# How to create a user and company name header in Flutter using Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

code to create a user name and company name heading in flutter

couldn't really do it
code to create a user profile and company name and mini calculator for the farmer to calculate gain and loss and also an area for the farmer to know how much he or she spends on feeds and how much gain he makes daily by the items sold and the names of people he sold to with a platform to store names of people and the money they pay using flutter

Comment: We don't work for you. We help you with your work. So post your work, where you are stuck exactly and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would suggest you to share some reference image so that people here might be able to help you out on how to achieve the desired layout.

Comment: If you want, we can set up a meeting, and agree on how you want me to build the app for you, and how you are going to pay me for it. Looking forward to your reply. Regards